# Format the DateTime into a string using DateTime.ToShortDate()

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

What is the proper way to use the DateTime.TryParse() method to convert the string to a DateTime object, and then use the DateTime.ToShortDateString() to reformat the data into the the string?
Output:
5/26/2016 12:00:00 AM
Desired:
 5/26/2016

To get current date and time:
 
`DateTime CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;` 

To Convert today's DateTime to short date:
 
`string CurrentDate=CurrentDateTime.ToShortDateString();`

To Convert today's DateTime to short time:
 `string CurrentTime= CurrentDateTime.ToShortTimeString()`

Resources:

[How to convert datetime to short date time](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/666326/How-to-convert-datetime-to-short-date-time)

[DateTime.ToShortDateString Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have you tried using format strings?

Comment: So what, exactly is wrong with `ToShortDateString()`? That would seem to give you exactly what you want (depending on your culture settings).

Comment: And also see [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)